# Why does this British speaker pronounce the word "gerund" as "/gerUND/" instead of /dʒɛrənd/?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, vowels

This is from a British speaker who teaches speaking skills to millions of students. In one of his videos, he mentions the word **"gerund"** but he pronounces it **"/gerUND/"**. [Speaking and IELTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=up8YOiCgz8Q) (see:15:36-15:46)

Saying **"gerUND"** is just wrong, isn't it?. And I listened to him again and again. He is eloquent and seems to speak with an RP accent, but he said **"gerUND"** two times, so it can't be a slip of tongue.

So, I got surprised, and even had to look it up again. And the dictionaries (Cambridge, collins, Merriam) say it **/dʒɛrənd/**, as expected.

I would not ask this question if he was not an IELTS teacher, too. I can't help wondering,why would a British eloquent speaker, who seems to speaks with an RP accent, pronounce the word **"gerund"** so wrong?

Could I be hearing it wrong?

Comment: Pronunciations /ˈdʒɛrənd/, and /ˈdʒɛrʌnd/ are both acceptable, but I found his pronunciation of *gerund* erm... unusual, too. I wonder if his regionality or age influences the pronunciation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, but all of the dictionaries I looked up and other web sites that pronunces words out loud including Collins, Cambridge and Merriam pronounce it as  /ˈdʒɛrənd/. So, if the pronounciation /ˈdʒɛrʌnd/  is also acceptable, why no dictionary covers it? Isn't it interesting?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) also transcribes it both ways. “In linguistics, a gerund (**/ˈdʒɛrənd**, **-ʌnd** / abbreviated *ger*) is any of various nonfinite verb forms in various languages”

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Thanks. I have checked them. It is good to seem covered in other places except for the dictinaries. Interestingly, when it comes to showing how to pronounce it,  they only say the first one, whereas there is another way of pronouncing it shown there but not said there. Should they have pronounced both?

Comment: I'm British, and his pronunciation is unusual, certainly not typically British.  The problem I think is that he is putting the stress on the second syllable like  je**RUND** instead of the standard **JE**rund.  I would consider this a mistake.

Comment: I think the / -ʌnd/ pronunciation is quite rare, but the letter "u" can be pronounced as /ʌ/  in many English words such as *lunch* and *bus*. I think it's a very good question, and it's clear you did some good research before posting. Yes! Billy Kerr has hit the nail on its head, the speaker places the stress on the 2nd syllable. It's very unusual.

Comment: His accent is absolutely not RP. It's northern, possibly Manchester. And I don't hear him saying gerAND, he is saying gerUND; the odd part is the stress, not the vowel sound.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -absolutely this. he is not saying 'gerAND'.

Comment: What @DanielRoseman said. The guy speaks very clearly, with something of a North Midlands accent, but it's clear as day that he says gerUND. For which the full OED only gives pronunciations with primary stress on the *first* syllable, but I personally am inconsistent on this one. I'm as likely to stress the second syllable as the first, and I really don't have much of a preference, so most likely I hear both versions reasonably often myself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it turns on a mis-hearing (and/or a distinction not recognised by native Anglophones).

Comment: I can't tell what accent he has; something middle-England, certainly not RP, but it's not helped by the fact he's …speaking…very…slowly…and…clearly, which would make it sound odd to most Brits.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.- I see him as a self-appointed 'expert'. I would like to be less complimentary, but will refrain.

Comment: The folks over at English Language and Usage might be able to better help with this question. I suppose the /-ʌ/ pronunciation comes from the Late Latin "gerundum", which perhaps persisted unshifted in parts of Britain.

Comment: Someone disputed the speaker's credentials, and undeservedly so, [Mr Keith O'Hare](https://keithspeakingacademy.com/author/keithohare/) has a degree in Digital Education and a diploma in teaching English as a second language (TESOL) awarded by Trinity College. There's no guarantee that these qualifications are genuine; however, his lessons on IELTS speaking and explanations are valid.

Comment: He speaks slowly and carefully to his non-native audience and consequently his explanations are simplified. I think he does a good job on YouTube but I did notice on rare occasions the stress on certain words were different from mine. I think this might be influenced by the speakers of his adopted home, Spain. If you hear *gerundio* and *progetto* (in this case Italian) for years, and you teach these things in your student's native languages your brain becomes accustomed to the sounds and sends signals that the stress on gerund and project is on the second syllable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Although I haven't ever heard the word stressed *only* on the second syllable, the pronunciation I'm used to has *both* syllables equally stressed and the second has the same vowel sound as "lunch" does. I wonder how common this variant is?